# Geometric construction of vanishing points from a length ratio.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Can someone please explain why the vanishing point can be constructed in such a way? The textbook I am studying shows this example without much explanation. From my studies, I know using the cross ratio one can compute the vanishing point. However, I don't quite understand why the method below works as well. I suspect this geometric construction might be related to the cross ratio in that the cross ratio of $\mathbf{a', b', c', v'}$ is the same as the cross ratio of $\mathbf{a, b, c, v}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is the point at infinity in the world line $\mathbf{l}$ since we are using the world line ratios $a:b$ but I can't wrap my head around this properly. I don't get why $\mathbf{v'}$ is the intersection of $\mathbf{l}$ and $\mathbf{a'c'}$.

For those who may not remember or know, the cross ratio says the ratio of ratios of lengths is invariant under a projective transformation. Here, letters with $\mathbf{'}$ are the points in the image line:
$$\mathbf{\frac{{a'c'}}{{a'd'}}:\frac{{b'c'}}{{b'd'}}=\frac{{ac}}{{ad}}:\frac{{bc}}{{bd}}}$$

Here is the textbook example:

> The vanishing points shown in figure 2.14 may also be computed by a purely geometric
> construction consisting of the following steps:
>
> 1. Given: three collinear points, $\mathbf{a'}$, $\mathbf{b'}$ and $\mathbf{c'}$, in an image corresponding to collinear world points with interval ratio $a:b$.
> 2. Draw any line $\mathbf{l}$ through $\mathbf{a'}$ (not coincident with the line $\mathbf{a'c'}$), and mark off points $\mathbf{a = a'}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ such that the line segments $\mathbf{ab}$    , $\mathbf{bc}$     have length ratio $a:b$.
> 3. Join $\mathbf{bb'}$ and $\mathbf{cc'}$ and intersect in $\mathbf{o}$.
> 4. The line through $\mathbf{o}$ parallel to $\mathbf{l}$ meets the line $\mathbf{a'c'}$ in the vanishing point $\mathbf{v'}$.
>
> This construction is illustrated in figure 2.15.
>
> Figure 2.14:
> [image]
>
> Figure 2.15:
> [image]